# Magento 2 ignoring new theme

Tags: magento, magento2

I am attempting to create my first Magento 2 theme.

I have created a new theme here:

```
/app/design/frontend/MyComp/MyTheme/
```

I copied the blank theme from `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/` into `MyTheme` and then I created/edited various files, [as per the instructions here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html).

In the Admin Panel I have gone into Stores > Configuration > Design and Ive set the theme to `MyTheme`.

However the front end it appears that my new theme isnt being used.

When I enable template path hints from the Admin Panel, the frontend shows that all the files are being got from here `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/`.

Can anyone explain why Magento 2 is ignoring my theme, and how I can fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You were not configuring in the right place, and you did not run command after configuring.

After you create the theme, you have to configure in Admin: Admin > Content > Configuration > edit “Default Store view” http://prntscr.com/k5idnm, and choose your theme then select “Applied Theme”.

After that, run:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If after that, the theme still did not display correctly, you can back-up and delete folder pub/static/frontend, then run 2 commands above again and press Ctrl + F5 in your theme tab in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache after you've changed theme, running command in console:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Also if there is no files in your theme, Magento will use theme fallback system.